# How can I check that 2 HTTP requests have been made to the same API endpoint using Angular's HttpTestingController?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, jasmine, angular-test

I'm using Angular 5 and Jasmine to test my HTTP service.

My HTTP service will make 2 HTTP calls as part of a method, to the same endpoint.  I want to check that the service does make 2 HTTP calls.

There is already a really useful `expectOne("route").flush([]);` method, but ideally I want `expectTwo("route").flush([]);` or `expect("route", 2).flush([]);`

Here is an example test:

```
it("getApprovers called twice with over 5 seconds apart makes two calls",
    () => {
        userService.getApprovers().subscribe(x => expect(x.length).toBe(0));

        setTimeout(() => userService.getApprovers().subscribe(x => expect(x.length).toBe(0)), 5001);

        // assert that 2 calls are made here
    });
```

Is there any way to assert 2 calls are made?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With Jasmine, you can `spyOn` a function and check call counts with `expect(spiedOnFunction.calls.count()).toEqual(something)`.

You want to test calling again after 5 seconds, which happens to be the Jasmine default test timeout, so the `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` has to be bumped up to more than 5 seconds in the `beforeEach`.

Finally, because you are using an async call with `setTimeout`, you have to test expectations after the call completes. If you call your `expects` before the `setTimeout` is done, your test will not pass. Here's how to do that using `Promise`, `async`, and `await`.

```js
// dummy code under test
const userService = {
  getApprovers: function() {
    // dummy function
  }
};

describe("Jasmine test with Promise, async, await, and over 5 seconds for async call", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 6000;
  });

  it("getApprovers called twice with over 5 seconds apart makes two calls", async () => {
    // Arrange
    spyOn(userService, "getApprovers");

    // Act
    userService.getApprovers();
    await invokeFunctionAfterFiveSeconds(userService.getApprovers);

    // Assert
    expect(userService.getApprovers.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});

function invokeFunctionAfterFiveSeconds(func) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      func();
      resolve();
    }, 5001);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.3.14/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/boot.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I'm not sure what you are doing with the subscribe and length checking, so I took it out to simplify things, but add it back in if that's critical to the test.